# Solving the Dirichlet Problem for an infinite strip

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry

I have been looking into the Dirichlet problem and conformal mappings, but am unsure as to how to find a solution $u(x, y)$ for the Dirichlet problem given this information:

The region is $U = \{\ x+iy : 0 \leq y \leq 1 \ \}$, and the boundary conditions are $u(x, 0) = 0$, $u(x, 1) = 1$.

I see this as an infinite strip in the upper plane. I am unsure then how to find a solution to the Dirichlet problem. I tried inscribing a disk within the strip and then using standard results for a disk, but ran into problems as the radius of the inscribed ball would have to be $\lt 1$.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas about different functions I could try that would work?

Answer (score 1):

The region $U$ is in fact an infinite horizontal strip in the upper complex plane.
The conformal transformation $z \mapsto \exp(\pi z)$ will put you to the upper complex plane, and then composition with the map $z \mapsto \frac{z - i}{z+i}$ gives you the unit disc.

So, we're talking about a conformal transformation $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
$$
f(z) = \frac{\exp(\pi z) - i}{\exp(\pi z)+i}
$$

Now the Transfer lemma says that a composition of any holomorphic function $g: G \rightarrow \hat{G}$ with a harmonic function $u: \hat{G} \rightarrow \hat{G}$ will give a function $(u \circ g): G \rightarrow \hat{G}$ that is harmonic. Thus composing $f$ (as conformal maps are holomorphic) with a solution $u$ (to the Dirichlet problem) in the unit disc will yield the result.

$$
u(w) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{1 - \left|\frac{\exp(\pi z) - i}{\exp(\pi z)+i}\right|^2}{
\left|\exp(i\theta) - \frac{\exp(\pi z) - i}{\exp(\pi z)+i}\right|^2
}}\text{d}\theta
$$

for any $w$ in the $U$ as desired. Notice the change in the interval of integration. This is due to our boundary condition vanishing on the lower semi-circle (counter-clockwise) and being $1$ on the upper semi-circle (clockwise). To figure this out, one needs to keep track of the boundaries as the conformal maps stack up.

In **general**, the Riemann mapping theorem ensures that any simply connected region can be mapped to the unit disc with a map that is bijective, conformal and has a conformal inverse. So generally, unless the given boundary condition tends to misbehave on the boundary (being at least piece-wise continuous on the boundary still ensures proper behavior IIRC), **for any such problem** you might be given, the only thing you need to do is to be able to **find a conformal mapping** from the region given **and not lose track of the boundary** in the process.

Comment: Re-reading it now, I would not claim that this solution is entirely correct.